# How many times can `__del__` be called per object in Python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, destructor

I saw some code where `__del__` was being called explicitly on an object which I found curious, so I tried to play with it a bit to understand how it works.

I tried the following code (I understand using `__del__` in and of itself is potentially bad, but I'm just trying to edify myself here):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.a = 123
        self.b = b
        print "a is {}".format(self.a)
    def __del__(self):
        self.a = -1
        print "a is {}".format(self.a)
        self.b.dont_gc_me = self
    def foo(self):
        self.a = 9999999
        print "a is {}".format(self.a)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 800
    def __del__(self):
        self.a = 0
```

and then tried (in the IPython console) the following:

```
In [92]: f = Foo()

In [93]: a = A(f)
a is 123

In [94]: a = None
a is -1

In [95]: f.__dict__
Out[95]: {'a': 800, 'dont_gc_me': <__main__.A instance at 0x2456830>}

In [96]: f = None

In [97]:
```

I see that `__del__` is only called once even though the instance a of `A` has been kept alive by the instance f of `Foo`, and when I set the latter to `None`, I don't see the destructor being called the second time.

The [Python docs here](http://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/customization.html) say:

> Note that it is possible (though not recommended!) for the `__del__()`
>   method to postpone destruction of the instance by creating a new
>   reference to it. It may then be called at a later time when this new
>   reference is deleted. It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are
>   called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

This seems to imply that the `__del__`method may be called again, though there is no guarantee it will. So my question is: is there some circumstance where `__del__` will be called again? (I thought setting `f` to `None` above would do it, but it didn't). Any other nuances worth noting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
xs = []
n = 0

class A:
    def __del__(self):
        global n
        n += 1
        print("time {} calling __del__".format(n))
        xs.append(self)

print("creating an A immediately thrown away")
A()
for _ in range(5):
    print("popping from xs")
    xs.pop()
```

That prints:

```
creating an A immediately thrown away
time 1 calling __del__
popping from xs
time 2 calling __del__
popping from xs
time 3 calling __del__
popping from xs
time 4 calling __del__
popping from xs
time 5 calling __del__
popping from xs
time 6 calling __del__
```

So, in short, there's no limit on how many times `__del__` can be called.  But don't rely on this - the language may change "the rules" here eventually.

Cycles complicate the situation because when a cycle is entirely trash, there's no predictable order in which the objects belonging to the cycle will get destroyed.  Since it **is** a cycle, every object is reachable from every other object in the cycle, so executing a `__del__` for one of the objects in the cycle **may** reference an object that's already been destroyed.  Major headaches there, so CPython simply refuses to collect a cycle at least one of whose objects has a `__del__` method.

However, it's no problem if an object "hanging off" a trash cycle has a `__del__` method, provided the latter object is not itself in a trash cycle.  Example:

```
class A:
    def __del__(self):
        print("A is going away")

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.self = self
        self.a = A()
```

Then:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> import gc
>>> gc.collect()  # nothing happens
0
>>> c = None  # now c is in a trash self-cycle
>>> gc.collect()  # c.a.__del__ *is* called
A is going away
2
```

So that's the moral of this story:  if you have an object that "needs" to run a destructor, but may be in a cycle, put the `__del__` in a simple object **referenced by** the original object.  Like so:

```
class CriticalResource:
    def __init__(self, resource):
        self.r = resource

    def __del__(self):
        self.r.close_nicely()  # whatever

class FancyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.r = CriticalResource(get_some_resource())
        # ...
```

Now a `FancyObject` can be in as many cycles as you like.  When it becomes trash, the cycles won't prevent `CriticalResource`'s `__del__` from being invoked.

### Starting in Python 3.4

As @delnan noted in a comment, [PEP 442 changes the CPython rules](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/) starting in Python 3.4 (but this will not be backported to any previous CPython release).  `__del__` methods will be executed at most once then (by gc - of course users can explicitly call them any number of times), and it will no longer matter whether an object with a `__del__` method is part of cyclic trash.

The implementation will run all finalizers on all objects found in cyclic trash, and set a bit on each such object recording that its finalizer has been run.  It does this before any objects are torn down, so no finalizer can access an object in an insane (partially or wholly destructed) state.

The downside for the implementation is that finalizers can change the object graph in arbitrary ways, so the current cyclic garbage collection ("gc") run has to give up if anything in the cyclic trash has become reachable again ("resurrected").  That's why finalizers are (will be) allowed to run at most once:  else gc could be provoked into never making progress by a finalizer that resurrected dead objects in cyclic trash.

In effect, starting in 3.4, CPython's treatment of `__del__` methods will be a lot like Java's treatment of finalizers.

Comment: The future is here. CPython changed the rules just now: PEP 442 says "Following this scheme, an object's finalizer is always called exactly once, even if it was resurrected afterwards.". I'm saying CPython because I don't think it ever was a language rule: Alternative implementations (certainly PyPy, probably Jython and IronPython too) have been working differently for a long time, possibly since their inception.

Comment: Thanks!  I said "CPython" in my answer too ;-)  [Here's a link to the PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).  Note that this is implemented for Python 3.4, not yet released.  It won't be backported to any earlier CPython line (nothing in the Python 2 line, or Pythons 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 or 3.3).  So "the old" behavior will continue to baffle people for years to come :-(

Comment: I remember for a while after the 3.4 changes, there was an issue where objects with `__slots__ = ()` might still have their `__del__` methods called repeatedly. Looks like it got fixed in 3.8, though I haven't found which change was responsible.

Answer (score 1):

*[The following information is outdated; see the accepted answer for changes introduced in Python 3.4 relating to PEP 442.]*

`__del__` is never called for objects being collected by the cyclic garbage collector.

Since in the first call of `__del__` you are creating a cycle, you would be relying on the cyclic collector to clean up

The only way `__del__` could be called again would be if you manually break the cyclic reference

Answer (score 0):

Tim’s answer is authoritative: finalizers, `__del__()` or otherwise (e.g., `finally` clause in generator functions), can be called arbitrarily often, due to [object resurrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_resurrection), and this is implementation- and version-dependent. However, from CPython 3.4, finalizers are only called once, per [PEP 442 -- Safe object finalization](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/), like Java, thanks to [Antoine Pitrou](http://pro.pitrou.net/).

However, this is begging for a Pythonic example. Here’s one:

```
import sys
cart = []
class PlagueVictim:
    RETORTS = ("I'm not dead.",
               "I'm getting better.",
               'I feel fine.',
               "I think I'll go for a walk.",
               'I feel happy. I feel happy.')
    DEFAULT_RETORT = "I'm still not dead."
    @classmethod
    def retort(cls, i):
        try: return cls.RETORTS[i]
        except IndexError: return cls.DEFAULT_RETORT
    def __init__(self): self.incarnation = 0
    def __del__(self):
        print(self.retort(self.incarnation))
        if cart is not None: cart.append(self)
        self.incarnation += 1

cart.append(PlagueVictim())
print("> Here's one.")
cart.pop() and None
if not cart: sys.exit()

print(">> 'ere, he says he's not dead.")
# Stubborn, aren't you?
cart.pop() and None
cart.pop() and None
cart.pop() and None
cart.pop() and None
del PlagueVictim.__del__
print('*thwack*')
cart.pop() and None
print('>> Ah, thank you very much.')
print(len(cart))
```

Attentive readers will note the `None` check, which is because module globals are set to `None` at shutdown in CPython <3.4 ([Issue18214](http://bugs.python.org/issue18214)), fixed following the improved finalization, and the `and None`, which ensure that a reference isn’t being stored in `_` (value of last expression) in interactive mode.